# Curl not responding

Tags: php, curl, prestashop

I'm developing a module in prestashop and i need to download a XML by curl.

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1260); //timeout in seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump(curl_error($ch));
die();
```

I can't have a response of curl with this code. After the 1260 seconds the browser just keep loading.

In the server error logs i have this messages:

```
Timeout waiting for output from CGI script /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php56, referer: (...)
The timeout specified has expired: [client ] : ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed, referer
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the webserver error logs?

Comment: Hi @Difster, thank for the reply. In the server logs i found this 'Timeout waiting for output from CGI script /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php56, referer: (...)' 'The timeout specified has expired: [client ] : ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed, referer'

Comment: Kindly, comment the 2nd line. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the server from which you're downloading the XML is taking a long time to answer